# Join not summing CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql

What I'm looking to do is show my current performance for this month, compared with expected scheduled wins to come in and then display the total expected amount, by product type.

For clarity, I have two sub-products that I'm grouping under the same name.

My issue is that for my 'Charged' amount, it's keeping the two sub-products separate, where as the 'Scheduled' amount is working fine.

The table should look like:

```
Type | Charged | Scheduled | Expected
A      3         2           5
B      1         1           2
```

What's actually showing is:

```
Type | Charged | Scheduled | Expected
A      2         1           3
A      1         1           2
B      1         1           2
```

The code is as follows:

```
select
t2.product,
t1.Charged,
t2.Scheduled,
t1.charged + t2.scheduled as 'expected'
from(
select
    case
        when user_type = 'a1' then 'a'
        when user_type = 'a2' then 'a'
        else 'b'
    end as 'Type',
    SUM(charged) as 'Scheduled'
from
  table
where
  month(date) = month(now())
and
  year(date) = year(now())
  and status like 'scheduled'
group by 1
order by 2 desc) t2 join 
(select
    case
        when user_type = 'a1' then 'a'
        when user_type = 'a2' then 'a'
        else 'b'
    end as 'Type', 
    sum(charged) as 'Charged'
    FROM table
    WHERE (status = 'Complete'
       AND str_to_date(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') = str_to_date(concat(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'))
    GROUP BY user_type
    ORDER BY user_type ASC) as t1 on t1.type = t2.type
```

I appreciate I might not be explaining this incredibly well (and that my code is probably quite clunky - I'm still fairly new!) so any help/direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me  .. you have error?   wrong result ?  is not clear your expected  result ..

Comment: So in Scheduled, it's summing the a1 and a2 properly in A, but in Charged, it's keeping them separate but calling them both A

Comment: i have updated my asnwer .. seems you have the wrong group by  (user_type instead of type)  ..

Comment: that worked! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some suggestion

you have a column product in main select but you have type in subquery and not product

you should not use sigle quote around column name

ad you have group by user_type but you need  group by type for charged

```
select
t2.type,
t1.Charged,
t2.Scheduled,
t1.charged + t2.scheduled as 'expected'
from(
select
    case
        when user_type = 'a1' then 'a'
        when user_type = 'a2' then 'a'
        else 'b'
    end as Type,
    SUM(charged) as Scheduled
from
  table
where
  month(date) = month(now())
and
  year(date) = year(now())
  and status like 'scheduled'
group by 1
order by 2 desc) t2 join 
(select
    case
        when user_type = 'a1' then 'a'
        when user_type = 'a2' then 'a'
        else 'b'
    end as Type, 
    sum(charged) as Charged
    FROM table
    WHERE (status = 'Complete'
       AND str_to_date(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') = str_to_date(concat(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'))
    GROUP BY Type
    ORDER BY Type ASC) as t1 on t1.type = t2.type
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to say. What would you suggest I use in place of single quote marks?

Comment: in mysql quote are for literal string value  and for a column name is better  if dont'use quote  and when you need  for composite name eg `My column` or reversed  word  use backtics